# Making background-image fixed when resizing window (CSS)

Tags: css, responsive-design, background-image

I have been stuck on this problem for hours:

I'm trying to make the position of an image fixed when the window is resized to under 820px.
I need this because the image will overlap important text in the header (same color).

The CSS:

```
#banner {
  background:url(path/to/image) no-repeat 100%;}

@media screen and (max-width: 819px) {
  #banner {
  background:url(path/to/image) no-repeat x y z;}
}
```

I have tried using '820px' and 'fixed', but this clearly does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@media screen and (max-width: 819px) {
  #banner {
     background:url(path/to/image) no-repeat x y z;}
     z-index:-10;
  }
```

Actually, adjust the z-index as needed